# Does one say “playing in” or “playing at” in “Children are playing [‘in’ or ‘at’] the playground”?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, prepositions

Which preposition should I use here, *in* or *at*?

1. Children are playing **in** the playground.
2. Children are playing **at** the playground.

Comment: We generally (but not always) use *in* when referring to enclosed spaces. Since playgrounds are often enclosed, using *in* is entirely appropriate, although *at* is also good. Note that you can still use *in* if the actual playground is not enclosed.

Comment: @Mick Which preposition you use could also be determined by your location in relation to the playground. If you were in the coffee shop next door and someone asked you where your children were you might say *They're in the playground*. But if you were at home and the playground was a mile away, then *at the playground* might be more appropriate.

Comment: Both are correct, as these comments demonstrate. In order to say which is better in your particular circumstances, we need to know more: how far away is the playground; how large is it; is it enclosed by walls or fences (which?); is it public or private...? Perhaps an answer might address all of these points; but perhaps we could understand more of "the real problem that you face" in order to help you with it.

Comment: [California Jim at English Forums](https://www.englishforums.com/English/InAtThePlayground/vhkjk/post.htm) gives a sound (if unreferenced) answer, which @WS2 précises well.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Surely it must be that *tu précises* and *WS2 précise*. :)

Comment: @tuchrist I admit I had to check that one.

Answer (score 1):

> "I was playing football in the playground"
>   https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/playground

and:

> "There were children fighting in the playground."
>   http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/playground

but:

> "they need more supervision on the playground"
>   *Oxford American Writer's Thesaurus*

This suggests there may be a difference between British and American usage - as confirmed by Google Ngrams:

**American English:**

[image]

**British English:**

[image]

Comment: The use of 'at' is quite common also; non-mention of prepositional usages in a dictionary cannot be taken as censure. As WS2 states, the different prepositions are not exact equivalents. And further, how the speaker envisages the situation (container, or point location) will influence choice.